# Is it possible to redefine the keyboard shortcut for deleting files to [delete] loosing the [command]?

Tags: keyboard, macos

Is it possible to redefine the keyboard shortcut for deleting files to <kbd>delete</kbd> loosing the <kbd>command</kbd> ?
How?

Comment: I assume you want to replace the functionality of 'delete' with the functionality of 'cmd+delete'. Is this correct?

Comment: also note that in the lingo cmd+backspace = delete and fn+backspace = (forward) delete; just backspace = just backspace.

Comment: It's about deleting files, not chars.

Comment: @boehj: correct

Comment: @Petruza but your keyboard sends the same keycodes should you work on files or chars.

Comment: I know, @koiyu, but that's not what I asked. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally it is possible to customize your own keyboard shortcuts in the Keyboard pref pane, but you cannot re-map the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

So in short, no, it is not possible to re-map <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to simply the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

EDIT:

This would be a "hack", but it just occurred to me that if you have a programmable mouse with an extra button, you may be able to assign the <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> key combo to that button.  It won't work using the built-in Mouse pref pane, but there may be a third-party app that can do it -- e.g. [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/) or [Logitech Control Center](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support-downloads/downloads/software/devices/3129) (for Logitech mice, obviously).

Comment: Believe me I surfed all the options on that pane, that's why I asked. Sad to hear I can't

Comment: + 1: Very clever re: mapping it to the mouse.

Comment: the mouse hack is ok, but my question was just out of lazyness. I prefer the hassle of pressing `command` than installing a software that will be running there for no really useful purpose. Thanks anyway!